# Dual monitors - waking up on w10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, wake-up

I have two monitors. One is connected by displayport (primary) and the second one is connected by DVI (digital). On manjaro everything is ok (except that DP is waking up 2 seconds after DVI). But on W10 (Pro, x64) that one with DP is not waking up at all (after going to sleep, because if I just turn on computer, both monitors are ok). I have to disconnect DP cable & connect it again, then W10 finally recognizes it. But if I turn off my monitors while going away and turn on when I come back, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reinstalling the drivers for your motherboard's chipset. Sometimes default Windows drivers don't play well with hardware.

Comment: I will try it soon. Right know I'm staying on Manjaro, I'm trying to reduce the use of W10 to minimum. But when I'll boot W10, I'll try it and let yout know if it worked.